# set different position and constraints for different Size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout, size-classes

I am little bit confused in size classes. I have created a project in this I want the different position for `wCompact hAny` and `wCompact hRegular`.

I designed the UI using storyboard and set different position for these size classes. Each Size classes have different constraints installed but when I run this It will not not given me desired output.I have attached some images please see this and give me answer where I am doing wrong or miss.

[image: constraints for wCompact hAny][image: this is the position for wCompact hAny][image: constraints for wCompact hRegular][image: Position for wCompact hRegular][image: output in iphone4][image: output in iPhone 6+]

Comment: please specify what u want to achieve? for size classes you may refer this http://www.sitepoint.com/building-adaptive-user-interfaces-ios-8/

Comment: For iPhone4, 5, 6 I want the output like 2nd image I posted for iPhone6+ I want 4th one image I posted but output comes for iPhone4 like 5th image and for iPhone6+ 6th image is there.

Comment: @SagarSnehi I'll tell you in your last post too...its mainly your constraints problem...if you give horizontal and verical center with width and height then why did you give top and bottom constraints...its chaos..

Comment: i am totally agree with  EI Captain comment.

Comment: Then which constraint I have to remove top and bottom or horizontal vertical to get desired output.

Comment: please send me some good example videos link. For iPhone 4,5,6 I can use wCompact and hAny or wCompact hCompact?

Answer (score 0):

Set wCompact hAny and wCompact hRegular UIViewController.But before apply Constraints select size from Attributed Inspector because we are not familiar with the size of wCompact hAny and wCompact hRegular but after selecting size we get idea of iPhone Size.

[image]

not apply centre Horizontal and vertical to the super view. and also Set Height and Width according to requirement.

[image]